# operator<< and operator >> overloaded functions

Tags: c++, function

in my class definiton i have the following friend functions:

```
      friend  ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Person& p1);

      friend istream& operator >> (ostream& out Person& p1);
```

In my implentation file:

```
       ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Person& p1)
      {
       out<< p1.age; //this is a private variable
      }

      istream& operator << (istream& in, Person& p1)
      {
       in >> p1.age; //this is a private variable
      }
```

But when I compile this, i get an error that says "ostream" does not name a type friend ostream& operator(ostream& out, const Person& p1).. the same thing for istream. Since these are friend functions they can access the private variables i.e age so whats the problem?

Comment: Have you tried qualifying `ostream` with the `std` namespace, e.g. `std::ostream`?

Comment: You need to include `<ostream>` and `<istream>`. Including `<iostream>` would also work.

Comment: your functions should also return the stream as well. i.e. `return out;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, your function should return something, so:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Person& p1)
  {
   return out<< p1.age; //this is a private variable
  }
```

and

```
istream& operator << (istream& in, Person& p1)
  {
   return in >> p1.age; //this is a private variable
  }
```

you should remember to add `include <iostream>` header. and `using namespace std;`

and most of all one typo

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream& out Person& p1);
```